# how do you create an empty data frame using a function in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
dput(xv)
c("Users", "Transactions", "Workload")
```

I need to be able to create an empty data frame based on entries in vector xv using a function.

For example, it should be like this:

```
new_df <- data.frame(
    Users = character(), 
    Transactions = character(), 
    Workload = character()
)
```

since the values in xv could change and number of entries in xv could also change, I need to be able to do this using a function?

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: If the column types vary and the number of columns vary, why do you need a function.  You can use `setNames(data.frame(....), xv)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
do.call(data.frame,setNames(lapply(xv,function(e) vector(typeof(e))),xv));
## [1] Users        Transactions Workload
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Zheyuan for making me think a little more about my solution. Since the input (as specified by the OP) is an atomic vector, it cannot contain heterogeneous data types, so my `lapply()` call that generates a separate zero-length vector according to each input element's type offers no benefit. It *would* offer a benefit if `xv` was a list, which can contain heterogeneous data types, but since `xv` is also being used to set the names of the resulting data.frame, it would be very questionable if it contained non-character elements. So my solution is actually not as sensible as I thought it was.

Here's a more sensible solution using the `do.call(data.frame,...)` pattern, which replaces the `lapply()` call with `rep()`:

```
do.call(data.frame,setNames(rep(list(character()),length(xv)),xv));
## [1] Users        Transactions Workload
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3):

As the OP wanted a function and because I commented `setNames` first

```
f1 <- function(nm1){
       len <- length(nm1)
       setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(typeof(nm1), 0, len), 
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE), nm1) 
     }

f1(xv)
#[1] Users        Transactions Workload    
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

str(f1(xv))
#'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ Users       : chr 
#$ Transactions: chr 
#$ Workload    : chr
```

The `matrix(..` part is stolen from @ZheyuanLi's comment.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi He made it a bit more perfect with the the column classes.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
MakeDF.R <- function(CustomVector){
  NewDF <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(CustomVector)))
  #Matrixes can be easier to make, and wrapping in data.frame() quickly converts them
  colnames(NewDF) <- CustomVector
  #give the New dataframe columns names based on the vector you fed in
  return(NewDF)
}
```

So calling the function like below

```
CusVec<-c('a','b','c')
CustomDF <- MakeDF.R(CusVec)
```

Returns

```
> CustomDF
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Or to get a data frame with a set number of rows (more efficient to slot data in, than to create a new row every time, if you know how many rows you want, before hand)

```
CusVec<-c('a','b','c')

MakeDF.R <- function(CustomVector,n){
  NewDF <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=n,ncol=length(CusVec)))
  colnames(NewDF) <- CustomVector
  return(NewDF)
}

CustomDF <- MakeDF.R(CusVec,3)
```